# Undefined function or variable 'x'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate two matrixes which I defined outside of the function MetNewtonSist using subs and I get the error Undefined function or variable 'x' whenever I try to run the code.

[edit] I added the code for the GaussPivTot function which determines the solution of a liniear system.

```
syms x y
f1 = x^2 + y^2 -4;
f2 = (x^2)/8 - y;
J = jacobian( [ f1, f2 ], [x, y]);
F = [f1; f2];
subs(J, {x,y}, {1, 1})
eps = 10^(-6);
[ x_aprox,y_aprox, N ] = MetNewtonSist( F, J, 1, 1, eps )
```

```
function [x_aprox, y_aprox, N] = MetNewtonSist(F, J, x0, y0, eps)

    k = 1;
    x_v(1) = x0;
    y_v(1) = y0;

    while true

        k = k + 1;

        z = GaussPivTot(subs(J, {x, y}, {x_v(k-1), y_v(k-1)}),-subs(F,{x, y}, {x_v(k-1), y_v(k-1)}));
        x_v(k) = z(1) + x_v(k-1);
        y_v(k) = z(1) + y_v(k-1);

        if norm(z)/norm([x_v(k-1), y_v(k-1)]) < eps
            return 
        end
    end

    N = k;
    x_aprox = x_v(k);
    y_aprox = y_v(k); 

end
```

function [x] = GaussPivTot(A,b)

```
n = length(b);
A = [A,b];
index = 1:n;

for k = 1:n-1

    max = 0;

    for i = k:n
        for j  = k:n
            if A(i,j) > max
                max = A(i,j);
                p = i;
                m = j;
            end
        end
    end

    if A(p,m) == 0

        disp('Sist. incomp. sau comp. nedet.')
        return;

    end

    if p ~= k

        aux_line = A(p,:);
        A(p,:) = A(k, :);
        A(k,:) = aux_line;

    end

    if m ~= k

        aux_col = A(:,m);
        A(:,m) = A(:,k);
        A(:,k) = aux_col;
        aux_index = index(m);
        index(m) = index(k);
        index(k) = aux_index;

    end

    for l = k+1:n

            M(l,k) = A(l,k)/A(k,k);
            aux_line = A(l,:);
            A(l,:) = aux_line - M(l,k)*A(k,:);

    end

end

if A(n,n) == 0

    disp('Sist. incomp. sau comp. nedet.')
    return;

end

y = SubsDesc(A, A(:,n+1));

for i = 1:n

    x(index(i)) = y(i);

end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `eps` is defined as `2.2204e-16` in MATLAB. So do not overwrite it with your variable and name it any word else.

```
epsilon = 1e-6;
```

Coming to your actual issue, pass `x` and `y` as input arguments to the `MetNewtonSist` function. i.e. define `MetNewtonSist` as:

```
function [x_aprox, y_aprox, N] = MetNewtonSist(F, J, x0, y0, epsilon, x, y)
%added x and y and renamed eps to epsilon
```

and then call it with:

```
[x_aprox, y_aprox, N] = MetNewtonSist(F, J, 1, 1, epsilon, x, y);
```

Comment: in which line? Also note that we cannot run your code without `GaussPivTot`. The errors in that function are upto you to resolve

Comment: Here's where I get the error [x_v(k), y_v(k)] = z + [x_v(k-1), y_v(k-1)];

Comment: You cannot store two elements in two variables like that. Replace that erroneous line with these two lines i.e. `x_v(k) = z+x_v(k-1);` and `y_v(k) = y_v(k-1);`

Comment: but the GaussPivTot returns a 2x1 array, how is that going to work?

Comment: That's why you must always create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to save the time of all of us so that we may run your code. Use this: `x_v(k)=z(1)+x_v(k-1);` `y_v(k) = z(2)+y_v(k-1);`